# Creating user spesific folders inside a main users folder in php

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to automate folder creation while registering to the website. After they post their usernames, a $u variable takes this value and the rest of the script creates the folder inside the main "members" folder. I'm testing the folder creation only but I keep getting wrong results like members/$u. My code is like the following I couldn't figure out how to put this into a function form.

```
<?php
$u='';
$structure = './members/$u/';
if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
die('Failed to create folders...');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, there's two things wrong here. Firstly, `$u` isn't actually set to anything, and secondly, variable interpolation *doesn't* take place in single-quoted strings.

For example, if `$x` = "HI", then `echo '$x'` will print "$x", whereas `echo "$x"` will print "HI".

Additionally, you *need* to do some sanity checking here. For example, if my user ID is "../", then I can create folders in the root of your web directory. Similarly, "../../../../../../etc/hi" will create a folder somewhere under /etc, on a sufficiently un-protected web server.